# Put a condition (count numbers length) in intersection list

Tags: vb.net

I want to output only the numbers made up of at least 2 digits or only 2 digits. if there is a single number (a single digit) in the intersection, then it will not be added to the intersection. So how do I do that? because I do not succeed or do not know very well the function of the intersection that does this.

```
  TextBox1.Text = LineTrim(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim intersectionList As New List(Of String)()
    Dim linesx() As String = TextBox1.Lines
    For x As Integer = 1 To linesx.Length - 2
        Dim firstBoxList = TextBox1.Lines(x).Split(",")
        Dim secondBoxList = TextBox1.Lines(x + 1).Split(",")
        If intersectionList.Max.Length = (2) Then
            intersectionList.Add(String.Join(",", secondBoxList.Intersect(firstBoxList)))
        End If
    Next
```

so if we have at the intersection:

```
2 4
1
3 4 7
2
```

in the intersection will be added only:

```
2 4 
3 4 7
```

> If intersectionList.Max.Length = (2) Then

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strA$(), strT$

strA = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbNewLine)

For i% = 0 to strA.GetUpperBound(0)
    If Not Trim(strA(i)).Length.Equals(1) Then
        strT += strA(i) & vbNewLine
    End If
next
TextBox1.Text = ""
TextBox1.Text = strT
```